# Chaining method PHP

Tags: php, methods, chaining

```
<?php
$sth = Framework::blah()->any_key['any_key_2'];
?>
```

Hello, I want to get 'any_key' and 'any_key_2' in blah(), how I do that?

Answer (score 5):

What you are doing with `Framework::blah()->any_key['any_key_2'];` is this:

Statically call the method `blah()` in the `Framework` class. The method call has to return an object from which you can get the property `any_key` somehow. The value of `any_key` has to be an array or something that implements `ArrayAccess`.

```
class Framework
{
    public static function blah()
    {
        return new ArrayObject(
            array('any_key' => array(
                'any_key_2' => 'blablablah')
            ), ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
    }
}
```

or

```
class Framework {

    public $any_key = array(
        'any_key_2' => 'blahblahblah'
    );

    public static function blah()
    {
        return new self;
    }
}
```

or

```
class Framework
{
    public static function blah()
    {
        $class = new StdClass;
        $class->any_key = new Foo;
        return $class;
    }
}

class Foo implements ArrayAccess
{
    protected $any_key_2 = 'blahblahblah';
    public function offsetGet ($offset){
        return $this->$offset;
    }
    public function offsetSet ($offset, $value){}
    public function offsetUnset ($offset){}
    public function offsetExists ($offset){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible or you would need to pass these as a parameter to `blah` in some way.

The key concept that is used in [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) or when implementing a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) is to return the object itself in every method.